# Vue.js - handling metadata with vue-headful

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

i am using vue headful for working with seo and making meta tag dynamic but this plugin is not working. title is changing properly but meta tag is still not dynamic  it is not showing on page source but showing on inspect

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my cas the reaso was that the Facebook was indexing the site without running Vue, so plugin could not work properly.

My solution was to create an **index.html** with some basic meta inside **public** folder.

HOwever I belive that there sould be other method to hook into vue rendering functions.